# How to get the first number from span=(2494, 2516) here?

Tags: python

I want to cut a text from the point where my regex expression is found to the end of the text. The position may vary, so I need that number as a variable.
The position can already be seen in the result of `studentnrRegex.search(text)`:

```
>>> studentnrRegex = re.compile(r'(Studentnr = 18\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)')  
>>> start = studentnrRegex.search(text)  
>>> start  
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2494, 2516), match='Studentnr = 1825010243'>
>>> myText = text[2494:]  
>>> myText 
'Studentnr = 1825010243\nTEXT = blablabla
```

Can I get the start position as a variable directly from my variable start, in this case 2494?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match` object returned by calling `.search()` has [`.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) and [`.end()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.end) methods that return the starting and ending positions of the match.

```
studentnrRegex = re.compile(r'(Studentnr = 18\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)')
m = studentnrRegex.search(text)
start = m.start()
print(mytext[start:])
```

You can accomplish the same thing with a different regex that matches the student number and everything after it. This will save you the trouble of doing the slice:

```
studentnrRegex = re.compile(r'(Studentnr = 18\d{8}).*', re.DOTALL)
m = studentnrRegex.search(text)
print(m.group())
```

The `{8}` matches 8 repeats of the `\d` and the `.*` matches all remaining characters until the end of the string (including newlines) as long as the `re.DOTALL` flag is specified. The full match is group 0, which is the default value for the `.group()` method of the match object. You can access the student number as `m.group(1)`.